# Query outputting additional values into the first cell (column header)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table that has 3 columns (**ID** [column A], **Date1** [column B], **Date2** [column C])
I have written a query that will return all **ID** where:

- **Date1** is not empty AND is BEFORE January 1, 2016 AND **Date2** is EMPTY
- OR
- **Date1** is not empty AND is BEFORE January 1, 2016 AND **Date2** is AFTER January 1, 2016

---

This is what I have written so far:

```
  query(A:B,"select A where B <= date '2016-01-01' and B is not NULL and C is NULL or B <= date '2016-01-01' and B is not NULL and C > date '2016-01-01'")
```

---

As long as the very first row in my table is not empty are no issues but if the rows above the first ID to be output (let's say the 4th row) then every ID above it (row 1, row 2, and row 3) is also output, together, in the first output of the query.

[I've created a sample here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b808MRD-VNyxYHMs2KmUKMITwYOsP4SUe-Wj-VA9cCU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `query` function has an optional third parameter, the number of header rows in the data range to which the query refers. If this parameter is omitted, Google Sheets will guess how many header rows there are, and sometimes guess incorrectly. This is why you see "ID a b c": they are all considered row headers.

Solution: specify the number of header rows.

```
=query(A:C, "select ... ", 1)
```